# Convert javascript object into HTML

Tags: javascript, algorithm

So I need a function that converts a js object of type:

```
{node: 'X', children: [{node: 'Y'}]}
```

with any depth into a string that is similar to html. For example the above should be converted into something like:

```
'<div class="X"><div class="Y"></div></div>'
```

This should be intuitive in a way that the order nodes are inserted into each other is same divs are.
So here is what I have this far:

```js
function convertObj(obj){
  const html_start = '<div class="';
  const html_end = '</div>';
  let current_parent = obj;
  let child_nodes = '';
  console.log(current_parent, current_parent.children)  
  if( typeof( current_parent.children)!= 'undefined'){
    let childrn = current_parent.children.map(child_node => convertObj(child_node) )
    child_nodes = child_nodes + childrn
  }
  return html_start+current_parent.node+'">'+child_nodes+html_end;
}
```

The problem is `,` between child nodes if they are multiple in number.
And here is my jest test, which is failing

```
describe('convertObj', () => {
  it('should turn node value to a div with class of the same name', () => {
    expect(convertObj({node: 'A'})).toBe('<div class="A"></div>');
  });
  it('should incert nodes in children to parent node', () => {
    expect(convertObj({node: 'A', children:[{node : 'B'}]})).toBe('<div class="A"><div class="B"></div></div>');
    expect(convertObj({node: 'A', children:[{node : 'B'}, {node: 'C', children: [{node: 'D'}]}]})).toBe('<div class="A"><div class="B"></div> <div class="C"><div class="D"></div></div></div>');    
  });
});
```

Help appreciated! You can run tests [here](https://repl.it/@liliggga/convertObjjest)

Comment: Concatenating a string and an array will call `.join()` on the array. Replace the implicit call with an explicit one with the proper settings.

Comment: @JonathanEltgroth I feel like like I miss a small bit, and starting over with JQ seems redundant

Comment: @Andreas good point, that is what I was missing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using some more ES6 syntactic sugar like [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Object_destructuring) and a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), you can make a very simple recursive implementation:

```js
const convertObj = ({ node, children = [] }) =>
  `<div class="${node}">${children.map(convertObj).join(' ')}</div>`

const tree = {node: 'A', children:[{node : 'B'}, {node: 'C', children: [{node: 'D'}]}]}

console.log(convertObj(tree))
```

Comment: This is beautiful. Where are you peaple getting this knowledge from ...

Comment: @seethrough I do have links if you want to follow up on documentation for those language constructs.

Comment: sure, I would love to, the test is failing because there is a space between sister tags

Comment: @seethrough you have a space in the unit test you provided in the code block (`expect(convertObj({node: 'A', children:[{node : 'B'}, {node: 'C', children: [{node: 'D'}]}]})).toBe('<div class="A"><div class="B"></div> <div class="C"><div class="D"></div></div></div>');    `), that's why I put a space in `.join(' ')`

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the implicit call of `.join()` when concatenating `child_nodes` (a string) and `childrn` (an array).

Just add an explicit `.join()` with a space as separator and your function works as expected

```js
function convertObj(obj){
  const html_start = '<div class="';
  const html_end = '</div>';
  let current_parent = obj;
  let child_nodes = '';

  if( typeof( current_parent.children)!= 'undefined'){
    let childrn = current_parent.children.map(child_node => convertObj(child_node) )
    child_nodes = child_nodes + childrn.join(" ");
  }

  return html_start+current_parent.node+'">'+child_nodes+html_end;
}

[{node: 'A', children:[{node : 'B'}]}, {node: 'A', children:[{node : 'B'}, {node: 'C', children: [{node: 'D'}]}]}]
   .forEach(test => console.log(convertObj(test)));
```

Comment: The other guy happened to answer faster, but thank you anyway, I upwoted your answer